# running external program before file is in a folder

Tags: python, jquery, flask

I uploaded it with ajax, python and flask, right after that I call an external program with that file that was loaded, but the execution in python happens before the file goes to the folder and then the external program cannot get the input. I thought of checking if the file was in the directory and just letting it run when it was but it didn't happen

I tried all the ways I thought, with while, with try except, with if, with os.path.isfile() ... but none of the ways worked as I need. In php the apache server make this post much more fast or i make something wrong.

the last code that i try

```
    def run_analysis(self):
        file = f'{self.BASE_URL}{self.INPUT_FILE}{self.name}{self.ext}'
        flag = True

        while flag:
            if os.path.exists(file):
                self.process_file(file)
                flag = False
                break
            else:
                print('file not found!')
                time.sleep(1)
    
    
    def process_file(self, f):
        command_assembly = f'{self.ANALYSIS_APP} {self.PARAM_OUT} {self.BASE_URL}{self.OUTPUT_DIR} {f}'
       
        result = subprocess.run(command_assembly, capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True)
        return result.stdout
```

EDIT 1:

@EAW here the code for upload, but it simplified:

```
    def handle(self, file, app):
    my_file = File(file, app)
    temp_path = None

    temp_path = my_file.save_file(my_file.get_filename())

    check_inside_file = my_file.open_file(temp_path + my_file.get_filename())

    if not check_inside_file:

        os.remove(temp_path + my_file.get_filename())
        return jsonify({'error': 'File is not in the format'}), 400

    if my_file and check_inside_file and my_file.check_extensions():
        new_filename = my_file.change_filename()
        my_file.replace(temp_path)
        my_file.rename(new_filename)
        new_filename_noextension = my_file.remove_extension(new_filename)
        return new_filename_noextension
```

In File class

```
def replace(self, src):
    dst = os.path.join(self.app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] + self.file.filename)
    src = os.path.join(self.app.config['UPLOAD_TEMP_FOLDER'] + self.file.filename)
    os.replace(src, dst)
```

I just, save the file in the temp folder and after that file is ok, i replace for upload folder.

thanks

Comment: If the file is not in the upload folder where you expect then it is likely that there is a problem with the upload itself. It would be useful to show your flask code handling the upload and then calling your external program.

Comment: i removed the mvc code for the upload function and put the most part on the route. Now itś working but is a little mess.

Answer (score 0):

Your code to check the existence of a file is fine, either your `file` string is malformed or your working directory isn't what you're expecting.
Make sure you know where the files are going to end up, and what they're going to be called, then compare with your path `file` and your working directory `os.getcwd()` and go from there.

Also you don't need to bother with `flag` or `break`, just check `exists()` :)

```
    def run_analysis(self):
        # make sure this path is being built correctly
        file = f'{self.BASE_URL}{self.INPUT_FILE}{self.name}{self.ext}'

        # simplify loop
        while not os.path.exists(file):
            print('file not found!')
            time.sleep(1)
        self.process_file(file)    
    

    def process_file(self, f):
        # do stuff
        ...
```

Comment: The string is functional. If i run this command in a terminal, the result is fine.